# MacExcel VBA - Copy chart from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I need to copy a shape from Excel and paste it on Word file. After pasting, I need to rotate it by 90 degrees and then change sizing of the chart.

Below code works fine on Windows OS but not on MAC. How can I make it Mac compatible?

```
shTPSRanking.Shapes("grpTPSRanking").CopyPicture
w.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial
With w.ActiveDocument.Shapes(w.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count)
    .IncrementRotation -90
    .Top = 173.65
    .Left = 0 '-139
    .Width = 773.8
    .Height = 337.5
End With
```

In Mac, it gives run time error with message "Method Top of object shape failed".

Comment: Please describe HOW it doesn't work on the Mac. And tell the world which version of the Mac is involved.

Comment: It gives error message as "Method Top of object shape failed"

Comment: Inter-application VBA works fairly reliably in Windows, but it's horrible on the Mac. I don't even know how to advise you to proceed.